# inline li elements with font awesome links

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have the following html:

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
  <li class="hidden">
    <a href="#page-top"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#apr">APR</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
    <% if current_user %>
      <li>
      <div class="fafa_inline"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><%= link_to "Log Out", log_out_path, class: "page-scroll" %></div>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li>
      <div class="fafa_inline"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><%= link_to " Sign Up", sign_up_path, class: "page-scroll" %></div>
      </li>
      <li>
      <div class="fafa_inline"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i><%= link_to " Log In", log_in_path, class: "page-scroll" %></div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Essentially, what this does is displays differently for users who are logged in and logged out, i.e., they will see either sign up + log in/log out.

What I wanted to incorporate were some nice font awesome stuff, which works fine. However, with the following css:

```
.fafa_inline {
    display: inline;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

they are displayed inline, but slightly above the other li elements, e.g.:

[image]

If anyone has a potential solution, either in the html or css I would be very appreciative. I'm absolutely stumped!

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align`?

Comment: If your menu has a fixed height, just set to the li the line-height the same as you menu.This should align the element in the middle (vertically). Usually font-awesome doesn't need you to specify a display property (your fafa_inline class) because the <i> element should be placed inline without you specifying anything.

Comment: @Nick For some reason the fa didn't display inline with this specific example.

Comment: @TylerH I've tried `vertical-align: baseline;' didn't work